# GUI Window for OpenSUSE

Tags: linux, java, swing, opensuse-13.2

As per Question "[Launch GUI programs from background service in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1224811/launch-gui-programs-from-background-service-in-linux/1224947?noredirect=1#comment1792563_1224947)"
I saved a.desktop with below contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Foo Viewer
Comment= The best viewer !
TryExec=fooview %F
Actions=Edit;Inverse
Icon=fooview.png
MimeType=image/x-foo
X-KDE-Library=libfooview
X-KDE-FactoryName=fooviewfactory
X-KDE-ServiceType=FooService

{Desktop Action Inverse]
Exec=fooview --inverse %f
Name=Foo Viewer (inverse image)

[Desktop Action Edit]
Exec=fooview --edit %f
Name=Foo Viewer (edit image)
Icon=fooview-edit.png
```

and tried to execute my Script : systemctl start serviceName.service
But it gives me below status :

```
linux-y78i:~/Desktop/Test # systemctl status RDPAutoStart.service -l
RDPAutoStart.service - RDPAutoRestart
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/RDPAutoStart.service; disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2016-06-14 19:17:20 IST; 18s ago
 Main PID: 1728 (java)
   CGroup: /system.slice/RDPAutoStart.service
           └─1728 /usr/bin/java -jar /root/Desktop/Test/Test.jar

Jun 14 19:17:21 linux-y78i.site java[1728]: Started
Jun 14 19:17:21 linux-y78i.site java[1728]: Current PortID :: gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier@7b98a1f4
Jun 14 19:17:30 linux-y78i.site java[1728]: AC06927#1
Jun 14 19:17:31 linux-y78i.site java[1728]: Connection String::jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xx.xx.116\cmsserver2012;databaseName = xxxxxxxxxx;user=xxxx;password=xxxxxxxxx
Jun 14 19:17:32 linux-y78i.site java[1728]: connection created
Jun 14 19:17:32 linux-y78i.site java[1728]: File already exist
Jun 14 19:17:32 linux-y78i.site java[1728]: Employee is : AC06927 ALPA A PATEL   SQLServerBlob:1
Jun 14 19:17:32 linux-y78i.site java[1728]: Entering to Web
Jun 14 19:17:32 linux-y78i.site java[1728]: Setting to Headless Mode::false
Jun 14 19:17:32 linux-y78i.site java[1728]: No protocol specified
```

where in my concern is to have GUI Window but it shows me **No protocol specified error**

Where do I need to change to have GUI Window through Service?

Comment: No likely connection between the .desktop and problems with the service.

Comment: means ? what do I need to modify.. I am a newbie to Linux

Comment: Maybe you could tell us exactly what is the software you are trying to install? (package name or URL to download) and explain us what is the original problem you are trying to solve (instead of problems encountered while implementing your possibly misguided solution).